# Pay for Logan Express from Boston Airport to Framingham

Tags: public-transport, buses

I'm going to take the Logan Express from Boston Airport to Framingham but I couldn't find a way to pay when I am on board on the bus from the internet. Is there a farebox on the Express bus so that I can pay in cash?

Answer (score 2):

You can pay in cash or card before you exit:

> When you reach Framingham they will ask you to remain on the bus and let those who prepaid to get off first. You will then pay before exiting.

([Source](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g60745-i48-k11195646-Logan_Express-Boston_Massachusetts.html))

Comment: I've done that journey tens of times over the years, and can confirm that's exactly how it works in practice.